# CAS Authentication and Authorization Best Practice

Tags: authentication, authorization, acl, cas, access-control

I have installed and configured my CAS to use LDAP for authenticating 100 over applications. I read in a few other answers about getting the authorization attributes from a different source like DB. However, I don't want to use LDAP grouping for authorization.

My question is what is the **best practice** to implement an **authorization system** that is easy to use and configure(simply with GUI) for admin and CAS? 
Also, I want to use the authorization system for centralized management on all my applications grants and permissions.

Image: 
[Just for resolution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DCArE.png)